# 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I just downloaded the SQLMembership-Idenitity-OWIN example and it crashes on login

```
User user = manager.Find(Username.Text, Password.Text);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have run the NuGet update and rebuilt the project.
I can connect to `ApplicationServices(SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN)` as far as I can tell it looks ok see user in `aspnet_Users` `aspnet_Membership` `aspnet_Role`

Comment: I'm having the same issue on logins. Did you find any insight?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  Check your connection string and make sure the user can read the proper tables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually exists a issue about this:

[The discriminator inserted doesn't match what sql profiler showed the library using to find a user](https://github.com/suhasj/SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN/pull/2)

This this forked solution, its fixed: [jcii/SQLMembership-Idenitity-OWIN](https://github.com/jcii/SQLMembership-Identity-OWIN)